# A problem about Borel-Cantelli lemma

Tags: real-analysis, probability

I am doing exercise in a textbook and I got confused with these two problems:

[image: first]

[image]

Fisrt, in problem 21,I noticed that "there is a subsequence $\{n_k\} $ tending to infinity s.t. $\mathbb{P}(\cap_kA_{n_k})>0$" is equivalent to "$\mathbb{P}(A_n$ i.o.$)>0$"

So in my opinion problem 21(b) and problem 24 are contradictions!

I proved 24:

$\mathbb{P}(A_n$ i.o.$)=\mathbb{P}(\cap_{n\ge1}\cup_{k\ge n} A_k)=\lim_{n\to \infty}\mathbb{P}(\cup_{k\ge n} A_k)\ge\varliminf_{n\to \infty}\mathbb{P}(A_n)\ge \epsilon$

21(a) is similar,we can just modify the last inequality to$\varliminf_{n\to \infty}\mathbb{P}(A_n)=1$

So there is nothing to do with Borel-Cantelli lemma??

Comment: What does $P(A_n \text{ i.o.})$ mean?

Comment: @DanielFischer After some googling, I think it means "infinitely often," i.e., $\bigcap_{n \ge 1} \bigcup_{k \ge n} A_k$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> First, in problem 21,I noticed that "there is a subsequence $\{n_k\} $ tending to infinity s.t. $\mathbb{P}(\cap_kA_{n_k})>0$" is equivalent to "$\mathbb{P}(A_n \text{ i.o.})>0$"

It's not obvious, but that is wrong. The existence of a sequence $(n_k)$ with $P\left(\bigcap_k A_{n_k}\right) > 0$ is a stronger condition.

> Consider a uniform distribution on $[0,1)$, and let
>  $$\begin{align}A_{2m} &= \bigcup_{k=0}^{2^m-1} \left[\frac{2k}{2^{m+1}}, \frac{2k+1}{2^{m+1}}\right),\\ A_{2m+1} &= \bigcup_{k=0}^{2^m-1} \left[\frac{2k+1}{2^{m+1}}, \frac{2k+2}{2^{m+1}}\right). \end{align}$$
> You have $P(A_n) = \frac{1}{2}$ for all $n$, and $P(A_n\text{ i.o.}) = 1$, since for every $m$, each $x$ belongs to either $A_{2m}$ or $A_{2m+1}$. Yet, for every sequence $(n_k)_{k\in\mathbb{N}}$, we have $$P\left(\bigcap_{k=0}^m A_{n_k}\right) = \frac{1}{2^{m+1}},$$ and therefore $P\left(\bigcap_k A_{n_k}\right) = 0$.

Your argument for exercise 24 is correct, and I've pretty much done 21 b) [it would be nice if you don't look before you've thought about it further], that leaves 21 a). I see no easier way than using the Borel-Cantelli lemma for that.

Comment: I agree with your 21(b) but there need further discussion.However I still think the two conditions are equilvalent since if we have$\omega \in A_n $i.o. i.e $\omega \in \cap_{n\ge1}\cup_{k\ge n} A_k$ so we can contract a subsequence.

Comment: But different $\omega$ may need different subsequences. The point in a) is that if $P(A_n)\to 1$, then you can find one subsequence such that the set of points contained in them all has positive measure. Part b) shows that that need not be possible if you only have $P(A_n) \geqslant \varepsilon$ for all $n$.

Comment: Oh,I see.Here is my proof for 21(a):since $P(A_n^c)\to 0$,there is a subsequence $n_k$ s.t. $P(A_{n_k})<\frac{1}{3^k}$ so by subadditivity there is$P(\cup A_{n_k}^c)<\frac{1}{2}$ .So $P(\cap A_{n_k})>0$.Still,there is nothing to do with Borel-Cantelli.